# What can I add to a pop group as one of two guitar players?

Tags: guitar, band

I'm new to playing in a band and have mostly played by myself or with one other jam mate. Now I've found myself in a little amateur band with drums, bass, singer, another guitar player an myself.

What are common ways of having the guitars complement each other and the song instead of competing for space? I've already understood that both of us strumming 5-6 string chords mostly makes a mess. Some ideas I've found for what one of the guitars can do are:

- Repeating a riff
- Play power chords in some interesting rhythm
- Play three-note-chords on the highest three strings, in some interesting rhythm
- Play a "lead melody"

I'm looking for a list of common ideas for my inspiration. I've tried to listen for this in different pop songs but found it pretty difficult, and would rather have experienced musicians guide me.

Comment: See also: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/80277/how-to-play-songs-that-contain-one-guitar-when-we-have-two-or-more-guitarists/80285

Comment: The options you listed yourself are good, and that older question has more. But really, I think the best option is to try out stuff on a piece-by-piece basis.

Comment: Great thread, thanks, I'll read it through!
@leftaroundabout - I'm sure that would be useful, but also that there's ideas that would take way longer to figure out by myself than when reading a list. E.g. playing those three-note chords, which I didn't even know was a thing before someone told me.

Comment: "... would take way longer to figure out by myself than when reading a list." -- There are no shortcuts; you can _only_ figure out how to play with other players by playing with other players and trying things out. What works will depend on whom you play with as much as on what you play. Lists of suggestions can help by providing starting points, but implementing those ideas effectively will take time. To add to your list: play 3-note voicings on the _bottom_ three strings (I used to do this with a mandolin player); play melodic _fills_; in general, listen for spaces to fill.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks for both the specific suggestions and the general advice on listening for spaces to fill, very useful. Yes exactly, I'm asking to find starting points and inspiration.

Comment: In addition to the answers to the linked question, which focus on what to play, you can also set the guitars apart in the mix by panning them left and right in the stereo field, using equalization to give each guitar its own space in the frequency spectrum, or more generally giving them each a very different sound (by using different guitars, pickups, amps, gain settings and reverb and/or by using effect pedals).

Comment: If two guitars strumming the exact same chord is making a mess, then something is wrong. You should be able to all play the same thing and have it work together. Then most likely cause of it sounding bad is timing and tuning. You have to be in tune and all hit the chords at the exact same times. Next thing to check is that you have different guitar tones and that you're not turned up too loud. That's all besides the idea of how to split up parts so you're not fighting, but you should be able to double each other also without it sounding terrible.

Comment: Have a listen to some of the groups from the '60s. A lot were comprised of bass, drums and two guitars. Rarely did both guitarsts play the same thing. There's little point in that. If you *are* both playing chords, at least try to use different voicings from each other.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Thanks, maybe our tones didn't go together very! I'll give it another try next jam. We were both doing "full" open chords with some standard strumming pattern.

Comment: @YourUncleBob Great point, thanks! Didn't cross my mind that the different tones interact. We were also playing next to each other, I'll try to put my amp on the other side of the room next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Have one guitar play power chords, the other playing full chords
- Have one electric guitar and an acoustic one
- Make pauses. Not everyone needs to play all the time; the second guitar can pause during the verse and come in again at the chorus. This will also add energy to the song when the second guitar comes in
- Have the second guitar "analyzing" the chords. Say the first one is playing a D major chord, have the second one play the notes one at a time.
- Have the guitars play the same chords with different effects.
- When playing the melody, don't play it in the same octave, have one of the guitars play it one octave higher/lower.
- Solos!
- Play in a question/answer style. Have the first guitar play one bar, followed by a bar from the second one, followed by a bar by the first one, followed by both guitars.

Comment: Nice, the electric vs acoustic thing, and with different effects, were missing from my list here https://music.stackexchange.com/a/80278/51766

Comment: Thank you for the list, this is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping to find! With playing full and power chords, do you mean that they would be played in the same rhythm?

Comment: @anna yes. Actually they could play in the same rhythm or change something